# Regular expression matching liquid code

Tags: python, html, regex, liquid

I'm building a website using Jekyll I would like to automatically remove liquid code (and **only** liquid code) from a given HTML file. I'm doing it in Python using regular expressions, and so far I have this one:

```regex
\{.*?\}|\{\{.*?\}\}
```

As I am not too familiar with liquid (and .html), could someone confirm that this will suffice for my goal?

Here is an example of the kind of file I will be working with:

```html
<div class="post-preview">
    <div class="post-title">
        <div class="post-name">
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-date">
            {% include time.html %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-snippet">
        {% if post.content contains '<!--break-->' %}
            {{ post.content | split:'<!--break-->' | first }}
            <div class="post-readmore">
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">read more-></a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% include post-meta.html %}
</div>
```

In this case my regex works, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something for the future. I could go for a hackish way and surround all liquid code with comments like

```c
/* start_liquid */ {blalala} /* end_liquid */
```

but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: could the downvoter(s) give their reasons?

Comment: I didn't actually downvote but I think they want you to give an example of liquid code to get a fully working example.

Comment: I checked on your code that you provided. It looks good to me and the regular expression I gave you below does only match the code embraced by either {} or {{}}. As described below I would only replace semiautomatically. I used Kate to verify by the way...

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, what you want to do with the matching liquid code? Do you want to delete it or do you want to surround it with comments? Why is your solution not elegant? I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: So, I have a bunch of html files like that lying around that I might have to clear from liquid code and then inject with javascript code with analogous functionality. So I don't want to manually go around and insert the comments, and neither do I want to put the comments again any time I introduce more liquid code. I also don't want to keep separate .html files with liquid and javascript since I might decide to change the HTML itself at a later point. Hence my problem :)

Comment: See the edit to my previous post below...

Answer (score 1):

The [regular expression](https://github.com/jg-rp/liquid/blob/e7c57a0c326296374a41bd115eb97d7b00d3cfbd/liquid/lex.py#L213) and [tokenizer](https://github.com/jg-rp/liquid/blob/e7c57a0c326296374a41bd115eb97d7b00d3cfbd/liquid/lex.py#L348) in [Python-Liquid](https://github.com/jg-rp/liquid) might be overkill for your use case, but will handle `{% comment %}` and `{% raw %}` blocks, and any multi-line tags. Something a simple regular expression alone would not cope with.

The [Writing a tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer) example from Python's `re` docs uses the same technique.

You could use [python-liquid](https://github.com/jg-rp/liquid) to filter out Liquid tokens like this.

```py
from liquid.lex import get_lexer
from liquid.token import TOKEN_LITERAL

s = """
<div class="post-preview">
    <div class="post-title">
        <div class="post-name">
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-date">
            {% include time.html %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-snippet">
        {% if post.content contains '<!--break-->' %}
            {{ post.content | split:'<!--break-->' | first }}
            <div class="post-readmore">
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">read more-></a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% include post-meta.html %}
</div>
"""

tokenize = get_lexer()
tokens = tokenize(s)
only_html = [token.value for token in tokens if token.type == TOKEN_LITERAL]
print("".join(only_html))
```

Notice the output preserves newlines outside Liquid markup.

```
<div class="post-preview">
    <div class="post-title">
        <div class="post-name">
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-date">
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-snippet">
        
            
            <div class="post-readmore">
                <a href="">read more-></a>
            </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am **not** saying that you should but you **could** use a "dirty" solution like:

```
{%\ (if)[\s\S]*?{%\ end\1\ %}|
{%.+?%}|
{{.+?}}
```

This matches all of the template code provided, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mH5aT2/1).
Additional tweaks would be to extend the alternation group (`if`) or use a parser altogether.

Answer (score -3):

I actually don't know liquid but I assume that a block of code is always contained in either {} or {{}}. I think it is hard to find a regular expression that will not match something like this:

```
print "This is my string with a number {}, cool!".format(42)
```

I would suggest that you open your html files with an editor that highlights all matches of your regular expression. Kate or Geany could do that for example. Than you can semiautomatically replace all the occurences with the empty string. I would however strongly not suggest to replace all the occurences in your code without checking them before. It is too likely that you will replace something important.

I would also use this regular expression:

```
\{[^\}]*\}|\{\{[^\}]*\}\}
```

Edit (see comments above):

From what I understand I think you want to have the possibility to have two versions of your code with either liquid or javascript. The only elegant solution that comes to my mind is to use git for that problem. You can create two separate branches of your project, one for liquid and one for javascript. This allows you to work on both versions separately and gives you the ability to switch between the two versions.

Edit 2:

I would also not give up on finding a better solution. You could also repost your question and make your problem more clear to the other users. There is likely a more elegant solution.